# Problems finishing off recursion with N_Queens

Tags: python-3.x, n-queens

I'm doing the N_Queens problem and think I have got myself a bit lost within my code using recursion & backtracking.

I'm attempting to solve this without using any import functions, or advanced language. I've reached a point where i'm really frustrated and would appreciate any solution and comments on the side to help my knowledge.

```
        global N 
N = 8

board =      [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

def printboard(board): 
    for row in range(N): 
        for col in range(N): 
            print(board[row][col], end=' ') 
        print('')



def SafePosition(board, row, col): 

  return (board[row][col]==0)

  def AddQueen(board, row, col):
    K = row+col
    L = row-col
    for row in range(N): 
        for col in range(N): 
          if (row+col == K) or (row==row) or (col==col) or (row-col == L):
            board[row][col] = 1       
    board[row][col] = 2

def findCol(board, col):
  for row in range(N):
    if(board[col][row] == 0):
      return [row]




def SolveNQueens(): 
  findCol(board, col)
  if board[row][col] == 0:
    AddQueen(board,row,col)
    if SafePosition(board,row, col):
      board[row][col]= 2
      SolveNQueens()
      board[row][col] = 0
    return



  printboard(board)

SolveNQueens()
```

It firstly says 'Col' is not defined which is confusing me, I secondly seem unable to advance from this current situation.

Ideally, the board should place a 2 at every point the Queen is placed.

Please go easy on me, I have only just started learning Python3.

Answer (score 1):

`SolveNQueens()` gets called first when the code runs, and the first statement is `findCol(board, col)`, until this point we only have defined globals `N` and `board` but there is no definition of `col`.
However, `row` and `col` *are* defined in other functions, so maybe we can also put those definitions in `SolveNQueens()` function to clear that error, something like:

```
def SolveNQueens():
    columns = [col for col in range(N)] # using previous definitions from 
    rows = [row for row in range(N)]    # printboard(board) function

    # can use one range here because board is a square
    # with same length sides columns and rows
    # either len(rows), or len(columns)

    for i in range(len(rows)):
        row = rows[i]   
        col = columns[i]

        # now we have row, col available
        findCol(board, col)
        ...
```

Comment: Hi, i'm not allowed to use the 'zip' function - any advice without?

Comment: okay I've replaced `zip()` with `range(len())` I think should work the same